# Watin test .exe file does not work in another pc

Tags: testing, exe, watin

I have problem with running WatiN test .exe file in another pc. When I try to run .exe file in my own pc (where I created it) it is work well! But then I run the same test in another pc, it is not work. IE is open and start testing but then program give me this error:

```
WatiN.Core.Exceptions.ElementReadOnlyExcption: Element with Id:Fname is readonly.
```

I know what this error mean, but gist is that this test have to work. In another pc there is not Visual Studio. Maybe it is need to install something?

Comment: Which version of Windows, WatiN, Internet Explorer and Visual Studio are installed on this other PC?

Comment: Are you sure `Interop.SHDocVw.dll` and `Microsoft.mshtml.dll` are referred by your EXE available?

Comment: Greg Burghardt : All programs are the same version,
Sham: You are right, it's not available for this reference. Thanks